# How to run a Github Actions runner to test Go Rest API Server?

Tags: go, continuous-integration, github-actions

I have a github actions file. I am just building the go application, which is a rest API server and running couple of tests in the test folder. But in github actions runner, it is stuck on the "start server" step indefinitely.It is not going to the test step. If I understand it correctly, the api server is running indefinitely listening to requests and not not going to next step. Kindly assist how I can run the below tests step.

```
name: Continuous Integration

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "main"
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: checkout repository
        uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Setup Go
        uses: actions/setup-go@v4
        with:
          go-version: 1.20.7
      - name: build
        run: go build -o main
      - name: change permissions
        run: chmod +x main
      - name: start server
        run: ./main
      - name: test
        run: go test -v ./tests
```

Below is the output of the actions runner.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaHHg.png)

Comment: maybe the `start server` step will lock the execution (active wait). so the `test` step is never reached (and a timeout is fired). In that case you can execute the server command in background like `./main &`

Comment: It worked. Thank you @Matteo!!!

Comment: you're welcome!

Comment: Please don't forget to mark the answer if it solved your issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the `start server` step will lock the execution (active wait). so the `test` step is never reached (and a timeout is fired). In that case you can execute the server command in background like `./main &`